# Why do I have to write PointSize in the vertex shader?

Tags: shader, vulkan

I got a Vulkan validation error as follows:

> [VULKAN][INFO] Vulkan validation layer callback: Validation Error: [
> UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-Shader-PointSizeMissing ] Object 0:
> VK_NULL_HANDLE, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PIPELINE; | MessageID =
> 0xf3693078 | Pipeline topology is set to POINT_LIST, but PointSize is
> not written to in the shader corresponding to
> VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT.

I've searched and found this information:

> The Vulkan rules for point size are a bit whacky. If you only have a
> vertex shader and you use points, then you must write PointSize in
> your vertex shader. If you have a geometry or tessellation shader,
> then it's dependent on the shaderTessellationAndGeometryPointSize
> device feature.

I'm wondering if I always need two different shaders depending on whether I draw points or other topology. I thought point size would have been, like the line width, decided by the pipeline state and set when you create the pipeline but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: "*I've searched and found this information:*" Where? I can't corroborate any of that. I can't even find the validation layer rule, as the error doesn't cite one.

Comment: @NicolBolas For me that validation error disappears if I write to it with gl_PointSize = 1.f. To avoid switching up shaders and complicating things I'm just going to write it always in any shader. Not sure what's up with the rules or why though.

Comment: You may have misunderstood my point. I can see how the specification lays out that if nothing writes to the PointSize, then the size for the point will be unspecified and therefore UB would result. What I don't understand is where that *specific* paragraph you quoted comes from, because nothing in the standard corroborates that. It sounds like some random user's nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

When rendering points, the size of those points will be defined by the value of the variable marked `PointSize` output from the latest vertex processing stage. The value of any such variable not written by a shader stage is undefined. Therefore, the behavior of rendering points with a shader pipeline whose latest vertex processing stage does not set this value is undefined.

This is different from line width because line width is *not* set by the shader. It's a pipeline state value. The point size always comes from the shader, and unlike OpenGL, there is no default context point size.

So if you want a shader module to be able to be used both with and without points, it's vertex processing stages must always write to a `PointSize` decorated output variable.

As for the anonymous document you linked to, those statements are dubiously accurate. `shaderTessellationAndGeometryPointSize` is a separate feature from `tessellationShader` or `geometryShader`. This means that it is theoretically possible for an implementation to support tessellation and/or geometry shaders, but *doesn't* support setting the point size from these shaders. And without this feature, the size of points emitted from either a TES or GS is 1.0f.

Answer (score 0):

With Vulkan 1.3 we have some extensions to `VkDynamicState` as specified [here](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkDynamicState.html), the one in question being `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY`. This allows us to record into the command buffer a different primitive topology, e.g. switch between `VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST` and `VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINT_LIST`. This was not possible before Vulkan 1.3.

However, the pipeline was still created with vertex buffer bindings, so if both point and triangle rendering should use the same pipeline they must also use the same shader program with the same `layout(location)` specifiers (ie. vertex attributes) for the input. So if the triangle rendering has a per-vertex texture coordinate, then the point rendering must also have a per-vertex texture coordinate.

It is absolutely doable to have point rendering lookup into a 2D texture for the individual point colors, but the point data itself might need a bit of pre-processing for this to work well.

This is an example of a vertex shader which renders point data:

```c
#version 450

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;

layout (set = 0, binding = 0) uniform CameraUniform
{
    mat4 viewProjection;
};

void main()
{
    gl_Position = viewProjection * vec4(aPosition, 1.0f);
    gl_PointSize = 2.0f;
}
```

In my mind though it's much easier and more practical to just create two separate pipeline objects.